# Problem with tf/Tutorials/Adding a frame (Python)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In section 6 of "tf/Tutorials/Adding a frame (Python)", line to change says:

(trans,rot) = self.tf.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", rospy.Time(0))

I believe it should be:

(trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/turtle2", "/carrot1", rospy.Time(0))

Thanks,
Tim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75013/problem-with-tf/tutorials/adding-a-frame-(python)/) by [Tim Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/6187/tim-murphy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess my real question is how do I correct the tutorials so no one has to waste the time I already wasted?

---

Originally posted by [Tim Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/6187/tim-murphy/) with karma: 31 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-28**:
To answer that: You can just edit the wiki - although just today it's on read-only as it's being moved to another server.